# Yasnippet for markdown code block

Tags: yasnippet

Trying to write a yasnippet for a markdown code block I wrote the following:

```
#name: Code Block
#contributor: Rovanion Luckey <rovanion.luckey@gmail.com>
# --

\`\`\`${1:language}
${2:code}
\`\`\`
```

Since according to the [documentation](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#outline-container-sec-3-1) you have to escape the backquotes. Though when I try to call on the snippet in my markdown document I only get:

```
YASESCAPE96PROTECTGUARDYASESCAPE96PROTECTGUARDYASESCAPE96PROTECTGUARDlanguage
code
YASESCAPE96PROTECTGUARDYASESCAPE96PROTECTGUARDYASESCAPE96PROTECTGUARD
```

Worth mentioning is that neither

````
```${1:language}
${2:code}
```
````

works.

Comment: This looks like [joaotavora/yasnippet#800](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/800), but I was unable to reproduce it, and neither was the OP after restarting Emacs.

Comment: Hmm, I just restarted emacs and now it's working as intended.

Comment: Oh I didn't update yasnippet. I merely restarted emacs. I'm on version 0.11.0 right now.

Comment: Had you updated yasnippet there in the session where you got the bad result? And if so, which version did you update from?

Comment: No, haven't touched my emacs packages for a month perhaps. This machine has definitely been restarted since.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like something happens to put Emacs into a state where yasnippet's escaping gets broken. If this happens again perhaps you could try stepping through `yas--snippet-parse-create` with edebug?

Comment: Absolutely, will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original example given in the question is correct, but due to [a bug in yasnippet](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/800#issuecomment-361359955) expanding a snippet which uses incorrect syntax will cause subsequent expansions to fail.  For example, if you first tried

````
```${1:javascript}
$0
```
````

This fails to expand properly, producing `YYYYY` (with error `Wrong type argument: char-or-string-p, (end-of-file)`). That's because the backquotes are not escaped.  But even after fixing it to

```
\`\`\`${1:javascript}
$0
\`\`\`
```

that still fails to expand properly, producing

```
YASESCAPE96PROTECTGUARDYASESCAPE96PROTECTGUARDYASESCAPE96PROTECTGUARDjavascript

YASESCAPE96PROTECTGUARDYASESCAPE96PROTECTGUARDYASESCAPE96PROTECTGUARD
```

(with error `Wrong type argument: char-or-string-p, (${1:javascript})`).  If you keep expanding a few more times, it will eventually work, as the incorrect internal state gets removed.

---

[The bug is fixed as of 2018 Feb 4](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/pull/895), in what will be version 0.13.  For older versions, it can be worked around by evaluating `(setq yas--backquote-markers-and-strings nil)`.